# to check authentication of client, who send a request to server, nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am server side and using nodejs
I would like to check authentication of client request. I mean, I would like to check if it is valid or eligible person or not who send request to me(server).
what is the best way?

server~client authentication

Comment: have you looked at http://passportjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented this yet - have been working with oAuth for API validation - but will use something similar to this http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/ for user log in/validation.